# Why does docker run helloworld on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 fail with `unable to apply apparmor profile`?

Tags: 20.04, docker

I've tried a fresh install of Ubuntu (release 20.04) on my cloud server and then tried to install docker and run the setup based on information from [Ubuntu's Official Page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

When I reach the step for testing with "Hello World"by running:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

I would get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

I'd like to be able to run docker on my instance.

Answer (score 5):

The error message gives little bits of clues, but most importantly says it has a problem with `apparmor`.  Checking my version of app armor using the command:
`aa-status` produced a not found message indicating that it was not installed on my OS.
I installed `apparmor` with the command:

```
sudo apt install apparmor
```

Subsequentally, I ran the docker hello world again:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

It was able to run and produce the correct output.

Comment: One has to wonder why AppArmor wasn't installed in the first place - I don't know if this is normal for cloud images?

Comment: It's a dependency of `snapd`, perhaps @avogadro removed it?

Comment: @ArturMeinild / @popey :  I'm using a hosting service from [HostWinds](https://www.hostwinds.com/) using their 'Unmanaged SSD Cloud 3' service using their Ubunutu 20.04 install.  After testing for `snapd`, it is not installed for some reason. I'm wondering if Hostwinds modified the Ubuntu image to be as slim as possible?

Comment: I would like to improve 'why' I got this error.  Hostwinds confirmed that they do use the standard Ubuntu server image for installs.  As a test, I tried to pull the latest Ubuntu docker image and run it to try out snapd.  Both `apparmor` and `snap` are not installed.  I cannot find documentation that says these _shouldn't_ be installed, so I'm starting to go down a rabbit hole here.

Comment: My system needed a reboot after installing apparmor.